# Datatables : table header does not expand, width not set to 100%

Tags: css, html-table, datatable, datatables

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZeL8.png)

Datatables : table header  does not expand, width not set to 100%
please help me

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read this (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), before adding more to your question (i.e. add your bit of html and CSS to reproduce the problem).

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example, a photo makes it hard to diagnose the issue

Comment: It seems to be a diff in the amount of cells in your table head compare to your table body, but without any code it is just guesswork